# Ruby replace img src https to http

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

How can I replace in a string all `https` from a image source to `http`?

```
<img src="https
<img src='https
<img title="title" src="https
```

Because of this type of combinations

```
"text <img src='https://image.com/img.jpg' /> text".gsub('<img src="https', '<img src="http')
```

will let https unreplaced.

```
gsub('https', 'http')
```

is not good because I don't want to replace the links for example.

Comment: Ideal solution will be for the web server to re-direct to `https` URL

Comment: If you just need regexp for gsub: `.gsub(/<img src=\'http/, '<img src=\'https')`; `.gsub(/<img src=\"http/, '<img src="https')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regex instead of a string:

```
mystring = "text <img src='https://image.com/img.jpg' /> text"

mystring.gsub(/\<img src=("|')https.+("|')/){|match| match.gsub('https','http')}
=> "text <img src='http://image.com/img.jpg' /> text"
```

Comment: It works great. Thank you. Can you recomend me where can I learn regex easy?

Answer (score 1):

If the image tags only consist of `<img src="">` (no attributes), you could o the following:

```
<img.*?src=('|")((?!https)[^"']+)\1
# look for an image tag literally
# look for src=" or src='
# assure that it is no https (negative lookahead)
# capture everything up to the previously captured delimiter (quote/double quote)
```

These strings need to be replaced.

See https://regex101.com/r/nA4yX4/1